# Print expression with [ ]

Tags: bash, text-processing, regular-expression, brace-expansion

I have an input in form `A[BCDE]GT`.
I would like my output to be:

```
ABGT
ACGT
ADGT
AEGT
```

I have tried to use `echo`, `printf`, trying to find something that might work.
Does anyone know some command that will help to execute this?

Comment: try: `echo A{B..E}GT`

Comment: In the general case, it's not possible to generate all possible strings that matches a regular expression. How locked into the particular format are you? Could you possible go along with a modified format, such as the one Isaac suggests, or `A{B,C,D,E}FG`?  Regular expressions are for matching against texts, whereas brace expansions (the example in these comments) are for _generating_ strings.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`, you can do something approaching by replacing `[BCDE]` with `{BCDE}`:

```
$ set -o braceccl
$ print -l A{BCDE}GT
ABGT
ACGT
ADGT
AEGT
```

If your input is guaranteed to contain only word characters and `[`, `]` characters:

```
set -o braceccl
input='A[BCDE]GT'
eval "output=( ${${${input//[^][[:IDENT:]]}//\[/{}//\]/\}} )"
print -l $output
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this, in shell with a script.

```
/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'input a letter (ABCDE)'
read value
echo A$value\GT
```

Note: check where are you env and bash, with:

$whereis env && whereis bash

```
/usr/bin/env
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Note that they have the input in the form `A[BCDE]GT`. How do you suggest applying your code given that string?

Comment: tks for the feedback, I edit my code.